# How to execute arbirtary expression in Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/asuXuDef/1/edit)

Consider the following directive:

```html
<div address
     street-address-model="client.streetAddress"
     suburb-model="client.suburb"></div>
```

```javascript
angular.module("Demo", [])
.controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.client = {
    streetAddress: '10 Morang Drive',
    suburb: 'Mill Park'
  };
})
.directive("address", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      streetAddressModel: '=',
      suburbModel: '='
    },
    template: " \
      <div> \
        Street Name: <input type='text' ng-model='streetAddressModel'> \
        Suburb: <input type='text' ng-model='suburbModel'> \
      </div> \
    "
  };
});
```

I would like to add another parameter to this directive: `on-street-address-change="<expression>"`.

Note that expression can be any valid angular expression, e.g.:

```
on-street-address-change="doSomething(x)"
on-street-address-change="doSomething(x, y, z)"
on-street-address-change="myVar = 'value'"
```

This expression should be evaluated once the street name input value changes (like if I had `ng-change="<expression>"` on the input).

How could I add such functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

html:

```
<div address
   street-address-model="client.streetAddress"
   suburb-model="client.suburb"
   on-street-address-change="doSomething(1)"
   ></div>
```

js:

```
angular.module("Demo", [])
.controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.client = {
    streetAddress: '10 Morang Drive',
    suburb: 'Mill Park'
  };

  $scope.doSomething = function(x){
    console.log(x);
  };
})
.directive("address", function($parse) {
  return {
    scope: {
      streetAddressModel: '=',
      suburbModel: '='
    },
    template: " \
      <div> \
        Street Name: <input type='text' ng-model='streetAddressModel'> \
        Suburb: <input type='text' ng-model='suburbModel'> \
      </div> \
    ",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('streetAddressModel', function(newVal){
          $parse(attrs.onStreetAddressChange)(scope.$parent);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/asuXuDef/8/edit)

**EDIT**: found much better way to do this:

```
scope: {
    onStreetAddressChange: '&'
}
```

And then execute it like this:

```
scope.onStreetAddressChange();
```

[See reference](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/oEo8ZAXv27/angularjs-isolate-scope)

Comment: Thanks fir the detailed answer! Any ideas why `doSomething` is called multiple times on every change?

Comment: Thanks! Could you just explain the importance of `.$parent` in the last line?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko when using `$parse` you are indicating in which scope should the expression executed. If you do this: `$parse('doSomething(1)')(scope);` expression will be evaluated in directive's scope instead of controller's scope.